# Apache Curator create with retry logic

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I like to know whether the create() method in Apache Curator wraps the original Zookeeper create method with retry logic or not?

I have written a bit of code that create a ZNode and I would like to that it is retrying by default. If not what would be the best way to write the create function with retrying capability?

```
CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("0.0.0.0:32770", new RetryUntilElapsed(3000, 1000));
client.start();

try {
     //make sure you're connected to zookeeper.
    client.blockUntilConnected();

     //Make sure the parants are created.
    client.create().creatingParentsIfNeeded().forPath("/larry-smells/foop", "tuna?".getBytes());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: The call to client.blockUntilConnected() is not needed. FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All operations in Apache Curator use the retry policy. So, yes, create() uses the retry policy. Note: I'm the main author of Curator.

Comment: What is the default retry policy here?

Comment: RetryUntilElapsed - whatever you use when constructing the CuratorFramework instance